# Dataproc overwriting executor memory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

We used to run a spark job on a Hadoop cluster with the following arguments:

```
{
    'conn_id': 'spark_default',
    'num_executors': 10,
    'executor_cores': 4,
    'executor_memory': '15G',
    'driver_memory': '8G',
    'conf': {
            'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead': '10G'
        }
}
```

We are now moving jobs to Dataproc and we can not manage to reproduce the same configuration:

We setup a cluster we enough vCPU and memory

```
create_cluster=dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create-%s' % CLUSTER_NAME, 
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME, 
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    num_workers=2,
    num_preemptible_workers=3,
    num_masters=1,
    master_machine_type='n1-highmem-8',
    worker_machine_type='n1-highmem-8',
    subnetwork_uri='projects/#####/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/prod',
    custom_image="spark-instance",
    master_disk_size=50,
    worker_disk_size=50,
    storage_bucket=‘#####-dataproc-tmp', 
    region='europe-west1', 
    zone='europe-west1-b',
    auto_delete_ttl=7200, 
    dag=dag
)


job = dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator(
    task_id=TASK_ID,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    region='europe-west1',
    main='%s/dist/main.py' % FOLDER,
    pyfiles='%s/dist/jobs.zip' % FOLDER,
    dataproc_pyspark_properties=spark_args,
    arguments=JOBS_ARGS,
    dag=dag
)
```

Using

```
spark_args_powerplus = {
    'num_executors': '10',
    'executor_cores': '4',
    'executor_memory': '15G',
    'executor_memoryoverhead': '10G'
}
```

It appears that the `executor_memoryoverhead` is not taken into account, causing the job to fail. Is there a default value in Dataproc we are missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Dataproc does not understand these short hand properties. eg. `num_executors` should be `spark.executor.instances` instead.
Can you try passing following instead as `dataproc_pyspark_properties` ?

```py
spark_args_powerplus = {
    'spark.executor.instances': '10',
    'spark.executor.cores': '4',
    'spark.executor.memory': '15G',
    'spark.executor.memoryOverhead': '10G'
}
```